# jQuery Lightbox 2 showing border in random images

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I have used [jQuery Lightbox 2](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/) and its working fine as per requirements.

However, It shows border in some random images. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

And here is the lightbox css for image which they are using.

```
<img class="lb-image" src="http://mywebsite/img/myimage.png">

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 4px solid white;
}
```

I have found out that this line `border: 4px solid white;` is causing this issue. If I comment this line, then border does not show.

[image]

However, it is not happening for all the image if I do not comment this line. In some images its working fine having border.

[image]

I have also checked how the image is uploaded and here is the full image which is having issues. (However, this is happening random images I guess).

[image]

So here I am confused what should I do in this scenario to be able to work for both the scenarios. Should I remove border or not ? Or any other thing I can apply for the same.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think border is displayed randomly.. it just that since it's white sometimes it blands in with the image. Try to change border color to something different to verify it ie.

```
border: 4px solid red;
```

Also you might want to check width and hight of the LightBox - looks like it might be hardcoded to square shape - meaning if the original image is not square (1x1) then you will see some additional gaps when border is on.

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me. I have checked and the image has hardcoded inline height and width something like this.  `<img class="lb-image" src="http://mywebsite.com/image.png" style="display: block;  width: 318px;  height: 318px; ">` (not sure whether this is getting added by lightbox or not) and i have also used this `border: 4px solid red;` and its seems to the same what you are suggesting.

Comment: I went to library's demo https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ and found out that height width getting added dynamically by library only. So I guess I cant control on this thing.

Comment: I guess it depend on the outcome (look and feel) you want to achive. If hardocded size works for your design you can keep it but then need to make sure your images are cropped to the size to match 1x1 dimentions. Othwerise if you want less maintainence work (avoid keep resizing images you are feeding into Lightbox) you will be better of overwritting hardocded Lightbox sizes to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Set height and width property of `.lightbox` to auto if possible.

if That doesn't work then try this. Since the image is transparent, the white background is from `.lightbox` element. And `.lightbox` element's parent has dark/black background, which you can see like a `border-right` and `border-bottom`. This is happening because your elements have fixed width/height arrangements. So change the `background-color` of `.lightbox` element's parent element to `white`.

It'll be better if you make a jsfiddle, since it's really hard to debug it like these.